# android java mCurrentLocation.getLongitude() trying to place into a variable to do a get

Tags: java, android

I have this issue where I'm trying to allocate a value from the gps eg location to  a variable and then build a string URL example :

```
double Myvar=mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

string myurl="https://www.someplace.com ? nicekey=" + Myvar;
```

and then, later on, use myurl to make a post or get with a volley.

I just wanted to know am I doing something wrong on how I am trying to concatenate the two to build a URL string how do I concatenate the value of mCurrentLocation.getLongitude() with my url.. ?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to create Strings using the `+` operator.

However, remove the whitespaces of your URL:

```
String myurl = "https://www.someplace.com?nicekey=" + Myvar;
```

See this for some other methods: https://www.java67.com/2015/05/4-ways-to-concatenate-strings-in-java.html